# How to see these two ways of computing expectation are equivalent?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume 
$$X:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i,$$
where each $X_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable with mean $p_i$. (We do not assume $X_1,\dots, X_n$ are independent.)

Then there are two ways to compute expectation of $X$:

1. By linearilty of expectation, $EX=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i$.
2. By definition, $EX=\sum_{j=0}^nj\cdot P(X=j)$.

I am wondering is there a way to see the second equation is equal to the first one? Especially we do not assume $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent, so it seems even computing the second value is difficult?

Answer (score 0):

For equivalence note that 
$$ X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \sum_{j=0}^n j1_{\{X=j\}}$$
where $1_A$ is an indicator function that is 1 if event $A$ is true, and 0 else. Then take expectations of the above and use linearity of expectations (and $E[1_A] = P[A]$) to get
$$ E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{E[X_i]}_{p_i} = \sum_{j=0}^n j \underbrace{E[1_{\{X=j\}}]}_{P[X=j]} $$
Now, we cannot compute $P[X=j]$ without more information about dependence/independence. This is why linearity of expectations is so useful: It allows a simple answer of $\sum_{i=1}^np_i$ to a difficult question.

#### Homework:

Convince yourself the equation $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = \sum_{j=0}^n j P[X=j]$ is true in these special cases (for which you can compute $P[X=j]$):

1) $X_i=X_1$, $p_i=p$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.

2) $\{X_i\}$ are i.i.d., $p_i=p$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.

Do these cases have different mass functions for $P[X=j]$? Do they still lead to the same answer for $E[X]$?

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses the [Probability-generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) of random variables. Quoting from Wikipedia, assuming 
$p(x) := P(X=x), $ we have

> ... the *probability generating function* of $X$ is defined as
>   $$G(z) = E(z^X) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty p(x)z^x,$$

The relation between $G(z)$ and random variable expectation is 
$$ 1 = G(1), \quad E(X) = G'(1). \tag1 $$
Define the sum of random variables
$$ X := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i. \tag2 $$
Then the probability generating function of $X$ is
$$ G_X(z) = \prod_{i=1}^n G_{X_i}(z). \tag3 $$
Now using the [Product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) from calculus, and $G_{X_i}(1) = 1$ we get
$$ E(X) = G_X'(1) = \sum_{i=1}^n G_{X_i}'(1) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i). \tag4 $$